# Why was Supernova paired against JaeDong in Battlegrounds Detroit?

Tags: starcraft-2, competitive-gaming

Just watching Day 2 of the Battlegrounds Detroit and they had Supernova and JaeDong, two of the strongest players, paired together, wheras another pairing was Minigun vs Shloopy, weaker players.

Normally the strong players are paired against weaker players in the early rounds. Why did they have two of the strongest players in the tournament paired so early?

Comment: Just the way the cookies crumble, I guess? They had the group stages, presumably randomly assigned, then single elimination. Better players should typically progress further, but there's an element of randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to the random factor of how they played in the group stages and then into the brackets.

This was the format:

> Format
>
> **Group Stage:**
>
> - Up to 128 players in 32 groups of 4 players each.
> - Groups are played in dual-tournament format.
> - Matches are best of three.
> - Top 2 players of each group advance to the bracket stage.
>
> **Bracket Stage:**
>
> - 64 players in a single-elimination bracket.
> - Matches are best of three until Semifinals.
> - Semifinals & Finals are best of five.

Here is how the bracket ended up breaking down. http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/2014_Red_Bull_Battle_Grounds:_Detroit

As you can see the bracket stage was randomly determined by the player's placement in the open stages. Because of the nature of the format of the Battle Ground tournaments pairings like the ones you put in your example can and will happen. For example, Stardust and Oz met very early in the tournament as well.